# How to set the token to local storage or cookies so that i can allow user to access certain web pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to build an authentication system so, i used node , mysql,express for that so now i am simply saving and checking user exist in database can access but now i added JWT to it, so now i want this JWT token to store in localstorage or in cookies so, can someone guide me how can i do so

this is my authentication controller.js

```
var Cryptr = require('cryptr');
cryptr = new Cryptr('myTotalySecretKey');
var express = require('express');
const ap = express();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var connection = require('./../config');

module.exports.authenticate = function (req, res) {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;


    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            res.json({
                status: false,
                message: 'there are some error with query'
            });
        } else {

            if (results.length > 0) {
                decryptedString = cryptr.decrypt(results[0].password);
                if (password == decryptedString) {
                    jwt.sign({ email, password },
                        'secretkey',
                        { expiresIn: '10days' },
                        (err, token) => {
                            console.log('token:' + token);
                            module.exports = token;
                            console.log(token);
                            res.redirect('/home.html');
                        }
                    );

                } else {
                    res.redirect('/login.html');
                    console.log("Wrong Input");

                }

            }
            else {
                res.redirect('/login.html');
            }
        }
    });
};
```

now i want to pass the token value to the local-storage or cookies so that i can restrict someone from acessing a page, i am reallly new to node js so any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I should notify you that **do not put any secret things like password in jwt payload** because the values of the payload could be accessed easily, you can try to copy paste a jwt in jwt.io site and see the payload.

set jwt in cookie like below, this will use [express cookie method that does set Http Set-Cookie header](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.cookie):

```
res.cookie('jwt', generated_cookie)
   .redirect('/home.html');
```

Also if you want to use **localStorage** you can set jwt in header and then in your code get the jwt from the header of login request and save it in localStorage and after that you should pass it as header in all other request, but this approach is a better solution for api calls like when you use react or vue ...

```
res.set({x-token: generated_token});

// In your code get 
// get token from response
localStorage.setItem('token', token);
// now whenever calling api pass token as header
```

Comment: aleahad using res.cookie('jwt', generated_cookie);
                            res.redirect('/home.html'); makes my application not respoding after i put the credentials in it

Answer (score 1):

I show you one solution using jwt token, you choose another way:

1. Back-end file e.g. api.js

   ```
   let jwt             = require('jsonwebtoken') 
   let secret          = 'yourSecret'; //secret key necessary to encode token
   let Cryptr = require('cryptr');
   let cryptr = new Cryptr('myTotalySecretKey');

   module.exports = function(router,upload) {

    function tokenAuth(req, res, next){
      let token = req.body.token || req.body.query || req.headers['x-access-token']
      if(token){
        jwt.verify(token, secret, function(err,decoded){
           if(err){
               res.json({ authenticated: false, message:'Invalid token'})
           } else {
               req.decoded = decoded;
               next()
           }
       })
     } else {
       res.json({success:false, message:'No token provided'});
     }
   }
   router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res){
     connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], function (error, results, fields){
     if(error) {
       res.json({ success:false, message: err })
     }
     if(!results.length){
      res.json({success:false, message:'User no found'})
     } else if (results.length>0){ 
      if(!req.body.password){
        res.json({success:false, message:'Password was not provided'});                    
      } else {  
        var validPassword = cryptr.decrypt(results[0].password);
        if(validPassword === req.body.password){                  
          res.json({success:false, message:'Incorrect password'})
        }  else {
         var token = jwt.sign({username: results[0].username, email: results[0].email}, secret, {expiresIn: '24h'})
         res.json({success:true, message:'You have logged in correctly!', token: token })
        }
       }
      }
     })
    })
    //If you want create a route for authenticated users for example comment posts, you can use our `tokenAuth function`
    router.post('/post/comment',tokenAuth,function(req,res){
      //access only for authenticated users
    }
   return router
   }
   ```

   This `tokenAuth` function we'll be use in paths restricted to authenticated users
2. server file e.g. server.js

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const app = express();
   const port = process.env.PORT || 80;
   const http = require('http').Server(app);
   const routes = require(path_to_api.js)(router);

   app.use('/myApi', routes)
   //***Here you should implement more details about your project such as routes, body parsers and other middlewares*****//
   //Connect to your database
   http.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`Server running on ${port}`))
   ```
3. Front-end file e.g. controller.js

   ```
   function(login){
      return fetch('/myApi/authenticate',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(login)
         }).then(result=>result.json()).then(data=> window.localStorage.setItem('token', data.token))
   } 

   //`login` argument should be an object and should be like {username: 'user username', password: 'user password'}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a user store cookies, you can use the [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header. From MDN:

`Set-Cookie: <cookie-name>=<cookie-value>`

In order to pass a header using Express, you can use `res.set()`, e.g. `res.set("Set-Cookie", "Token=" + token)`. I also suggest you use the `HttpOnly` cookie directive, since it seems from your post that you don't access this token directly via Javascript and you simply want to check it when the client requests a webpage: `res.set("Set-Cookie", "Token=" + token + "; HttpOnly")`.

The client will send the `Cookie` header to you when it requests a resource. You can check this header using `req.header('Cookie')`, and the output will be `"Token=<token>"` if the user is authenticated. You can then check this token for authenticity.

Comment: i have tried this res.set("Set-Cookie", "Token=" + token);
                            res.redirect('/home.html'); but i am not able to set the cookies to it as i am seeing in the developer application console it is still empty